# What's the better way to add an inline script?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, javascript

What's the better way to add an inline script in WordPress theme or plugin? Is it by the function `wp_add_inline_script`, or using the hook `wp_footer`? and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_add_inline_script()` is intended to be used for inline scripts that use or depend on another script that's been enqueued with `wp_enqueue_script()`. It ensures that the inline script is placed appropriately relative to the main script and will won't appear if the main script is unregistered. The example from [the announcement](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/08/enhanced-script-loader-in-wordpress-4-5/) was using Typekit:

```
function mytheme_enqueue_typekit() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-typekit', 'https://use.typekit.net/<typekit-id>.js', array(), '1.0' );
   wp_add_inline_script( 'mytheme-typekit', 'try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_typekit' );
```

Which results in

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://use.typekit.net/<typekit-id>.js?ver=1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}
</script>
```

Hooking into `wp_footer` is perfectly fine, but if your script depends on another script being loaded first it is less reliable, because you need to manually make sure that you add it in the correct place and properly remove it if the script is dequeued so that errors don't occur.

If your script does not depend on another script, and needs to be inline, then `wp_footer` would be the way to go.